# Split the excel input data to appear after a set amount of time

Tags: javascript, excel, async-await, promise, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot that reads data from an excel files and output each row data after a fixed amount of time.

excel format

```
stt word reading definition
stt word reading definition
stt word reading definition
```

my code

```js
const readXlsxFile = require("read-excel-file/node");

async function outputExcelList(message, filename) {
  try {
    // const schema; then some code...


    const excelFile = await readXlsxFile(`./vocablist/${filename}`, { schema });
//read from an excel file into an excelFile object containing all rows data as json format
    

    excelFile.rows.forEach((row) => {
      message.channel
        .send(`${row.stt}\t${row.word}`)
        .then((res) => wait(3))
        .then((res) =>
          message.channel.send(`${row.reading}\n${row.defintion}`)
        );
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Couldn't read excel list" + error);
  }
}

const wait = function (sec) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, sec * 1000);
  });
};
```

Things get a bit complicated for me when I want to split each row data in two sections. First one `stt word` would show up then after a set amount of time the rest `reading definition` would show. Then continue to another row object.

`excelFile` contains all rows from the parsed excel file as an object. `rows` is an array containing all row data objects.

My current code's output :
All the data rows of `` (`${row.stt}\t${row.word}`) `` are outputted at same time, then wait 3s then all `` (`${row.reading}\n${row.defintion}`) `` are outputted.

What I want:
Each `` (`${row.stt}\t${row.word}`) `` is outputted then wait 3s, then the rest of the row `` (`${row.reading}\n${row.defintion}`) ``. Only then another iteration would continue into another row.

**simple data illustration, abc and 123 only to illustrate the data section**

```sh
rows = [{a, b, 1, 2}, {c, d, 3, 4}, {e, f, 5, 6}....]
```

my code output

```sh
ab
cd
ef
//wait some sec
12
34
56
```

what I want

```sh
ab
//wait some sec
12

cd
//wait some sec
34

ef
//wait some sec
56
```

I'm thinking I'm not doing the loop or using promise correctly (and the first result is quite expected with order of promise chaining here I think).

Could you point out where am I doing it wrong and a basic solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this omg xDDD! after so many attemps.

I came into this article while thinking about a possible solution: https://www.hacksparrow.com/javascript/foreach-in-promise-async-function.html

The idea was `forEach` may not work as expected (due to the way the fucntion was built) when looping through promises. Then I changed the original `forEach` loop into a basic `for` loop and things worked.